# How to embed Ted talks videos with time var

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to embed Ted talks videos with a time variable.
On their website, if you add an anchor id like #t-618000 after the url, it works. 
Eg. https://www.ted.com/talks/hans_rosling_at_state#t-618000

When I try an embed with the time variable, it does not work :

```
<iframe src="https://embed.ted.com/talks/christopher_soghoian_your_smartphone_is_a_civil_rights_issue#t-23580" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

How can I find the javascript piece of code using this variable to change the player time?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [playback range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range) by including

```
#t=[starttime][,endtime]
```

as a fragment at end of URL pointing to media resource.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do this with the embed of the video on my website

Comment: What is stopping you from adding the fragment identifier to the URL at `src` of element?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work (see example in the edited post)

Comment: Use `=` instead of `-`. You can also set [`HTMLMediaElement.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) then call `HTMLMediaElement.play()` at `canplaythrough` event.

Comment: @AlphaNico Yes. Returns expected result, here.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code? I used = instead of - and still not working

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. Unfortunately it does not work with the ted talk's url : http://plnkr.co/edit/dN00cbvncUYkEeouAX45?p=preview

Comment: The video size is only `81.2kb`. The total duration of the media playback is less than one second

Comment: It works thanks! The thing is, the time references of the transcript ([link](https://www.ted.com/talks/christopher_soghoian_your_smartphone_is_a_civil_rights_issue/transcript)) are weird...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127100/discussion-between-alphanico-and-guest271314).